# how long will it take to execute a ten-stage pipeline

Tags: mathematical-foundations, cpu-pipelines

Suppose you design a computer with a `ten-stage` Pipeline to execute one instruction, with each stage taking `5nsec`

A)how long will it take to execute a program that has `30 sequential` instructions. 
**Answer: 195nsec**

B) how long will it take to execute a program that has `30 sequential instructions` in a `non-pipeline computer`
**Answer: 1500nsec**

can some one please help me to understand how was the answer achieved.

Comment: I suggest that you read up on how pipelines work. These are very simple calculations once you understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first instruction enters the pipeline at time $0$.  Each successive instruction enters $5$ ns after the previous one.  The first instruction exits the pipeline at time $10\cdot 5$ ns and each of the other $29$ instructions exits $5$ ns after the previous one.  In sum, $10 \cdot 5 + 29 \cdot 5 = 195$ ns.

For the non-pipelined processor, the somewhat pessimistic assumption is made that each instruction takes $10\cdot 5$ ns to execute; then, $30 \cdot 50 = 1500$.

Answer (score 1):

An instruction needs 10 times 5 nsec to execute. With pipelining, the next instruction can start when the previous one is in the next pipeline stage, that is 5 nsecs after the previous one started. Without pipelining, the next instruction starts only when the previous one has finished, that is after 10 times 5 sec. The rest is basic arithmetic.